# How to obtain answers when there are more than one correct answer using an array using php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have an issue with checking the correct answers from two arrays. The first are the correct answers, where it can have either one up to four possible correct answers.

```
{
"17":"nukequiz",
"18":"",
"13":"hard dRiVe",
"20":"false",
"15":"nukequiz",
"16":"National Speed Limit",
"14":"nukequiz",
"19":["Hue Edwards","Mark Spencer","Mark Smith"]
}
```

How can I check that each of the users answers for question 19 matches the correct answer?

[correct_answer] => Kate Lewington,Mark Smith

I have tried using array diff, but that just tell me if there are more answers from the user than there are correct answers! This is useful, but does not check each user answer against each correct answer.

The code I have is not exactly great, but does work for either short, multiple choice single answers and true or false answers.

```
    foreach($result as $row) {
        
        if(!is_array($data[$row['quesid']]) && 
            !is_array($row['correct_answer'])) 
        {
            $row['correct_answer'] = strtolower($row['correct_answer']);
            $data[$row['quesid']] = strtolower($data[$row['quesid']]);
        }
        if($row['correct_answer'] == $data[$row['quesid']]){ 
            echo '<tr style="background-color:#060">
<td colspan="2">Correct Answer: '.$row['correct_answer'].'</td>
<td colspan="2">User Answer:  '.$data[$row['quesid']].'</td>
                </tr>';
            $points = $row['points'];
            $score = $score + $points;
            $right_answer++;
        }
```

// Checks for either empty string from text box or hidden value in radio group using nukequiz to show its empty. Using no hidden field always results in "no" showing up due to to Jquery.

```
elseif($data[$row['quesid']] == 'nukequiz' || $data[$row['quesid']] == ""   )
{
echo '<tr style="background-color:#999">
<td colspan="2">Correct Answer:  '.$row['correct_answer'].'</td>
<td colspan="2">User Answer:  '.$data[$row['quesid']].'</td>
            </tr>';
        $unanswered++;
} elseif(!is_string($data[$row['quesid']]) && 
        is_array($data[$row['quesid']])) 
{
$cAnswer  = explode (",", $row['correct_answer']);
$uAnswer = $data[$row['quesid']];
$cAnswer = array_map( 'strtolower', $cAnswer );
$uAnswer = array_map( 'strtolower', $uAnswer );
array_multisort($cAnswer);
array_multisort($uAnswer);
$cntanswers = count($cAnswer);

} else  {
echo '<tr style="background-color:#930">
<td colspan="2">Correct Answer: '.$row['correct_answer'].'</td>
<td colspan="2">User Answer:  '.$data[$row['quesid']].'</td></tr>';
        $wrong_answer++;
    }
}
```

I need any ideas as to how to separate the user answers and check them against each correct answer.

Array diff is useful but only tells me what is not in the correct answer array.

Any help would be gratefully received if someone can at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: Look up [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) in the PHP manual

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is marked with '// ////////////////SOLUTION'. I used some test data to run the code.

```
$result = array(
    array(
        'quesid' => 13,
        'correct_answer' => 'hard dRiVe',
        'points' => 10
    ),
    array(
        'quesid' => 16,
        'correct_answer' => 'National Speed Limit',
        'points' => 10
    ),
    array(
        'quesid' => 19,
        'correct_answer' => 'Hue Edwards,Mark Spencer,Mark Smith',
        'points' => 10
    ),
);

$data = array(
        13 => 'Wrong Answer',
        16 => 'National Speed Limit',
        19 => array('Hue Edwards')
);

echo '<table>';
foreach($result as $row) {

    echo '==='.$row['quesid'].'===<hr>';
    echo '==='.$row['correct_answer'].'===<hr>';
    echo '==='.$row['points'].'===<hr>';
    echo '==='.$data[$row['quesid']].'===<hr>';
    // echo $k['boards']['price'];

    //$Canswer = array_map( 'strtolower', $row['correct_answer'] );
    if(!is_array($data[$row['quesid']]) &&
        !is_array($row['correct_answer']))
    {
        $row['correct_answer'] = strtolower($row['correct_answer']);
        $data[$row['quesid']] = strtolower($data[$row['quesid']]);
    }
    if($row['correct_answer'] == $data[$row['quesid']]){
        echo '<tr style="background-color:#060">
                <td colspan="2">Correct Answer:  '.$row['correct_answer'].'</td>
                <td colspan="2">User Answer:  '.$data[$row['quesid']].'</td>
            </tr>';
        $points = $row['points'];
        $score = $score + $points;
        $right_answer++;
    }
    // Checks for either empty string from text box or hidden value in radio group using nukequiz to show its empty. Using no hidden field always results in "no" showing up due to to Jquery.
    elseif($data[$row['quesid']] == 'nukequiz' || $data[$row['quesid']] == "" )
    {
        echo '<tr style="background-color:#999">
                <td colspan="2">Correct Answer:  '.$row['correct_answer'].'</td>
                <td colspan="2">User Answer:  '.$data[$row['quesid']].'</td>
            </tr>';
        $unanswered++;
    } elseif(!is_string($data[$row['quesid']]) &&
            is_array($data[$row['quesid']]))
    {
        $cAnswer  = explode (",", $row['correct_answer']);
        $uAnswer = $data[$row['quesid']];
        $cAnswer = array_map( 'strtolower', $cAnswer );
        $uAnswer = array_map( 'strtolower', $uAnswer );
        array_multisort($cAnswer);
        array_multisort($uAnswer);

        // ////////////////SOLUTION
        foreach($uAnswer as $answer){
            if(in_array($answer, $cAnswer)){
                echo '<tr style="background-color:#999">
                    <td colspan="2">Correct Answer:  '.$row['correct_answer'].'</td>
                    <td colspan="2">User Answer:  '.$answer.'</td>
                </tr>';   // For each user's answer, it creates a line in the table
            }
        }
        ///////////////////////////

    } else {
        echo '<tr style="background-color:#930">
                <td colspan="2">Correct Answer: '.$row['correct_answer'].'</td>
                <td colspan="2">User Answer:  '.$data[$row['quesid']].'</td>
            </tr>';
        $wrong_answer++;
    }
}
echo '<table>';
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I have looked at it and tried the code, but seems not to list each user answer as you mentioned. I have used for size of to extract each user answer bit then, when trying to extract each correct answer, it did it in pairs, which is not useful.  Thanks

Comment: Can you create some test tables (like $result and $data, that I have in my answer). Give me also a result table, so I can understand the correct output.

Comment: Hi I have put your code in place and adapted it slightly and it does work, extracting the right matches against the wrong ones now. My question would be, is it possible to extract each correct answer and each user answer and either match them as correct $a == $b or not matching $a !== $b? The data you used is fine as an example. If it can't be done, then I'll use what I have as it does as I mentioned work. So thanks for the assistance. See above re-edited code.